# Autofill Destination VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 worksheets, Data & Convert.

[image]

Trying to do an autofill in "Convert" based on "Data" last row (can be longer than 100 rows) by using this macro:-

```
Public Sub Call_Generate_Data()


    Sheets("Convert").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(Data!RC[4],Links!R1C1:R14C2,2,FALSE)"
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(Data!RC[12]="""",""1/1/2014"",Data!RC[12])"
    Range("B3").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:B" & Sheets("Data").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("B3").Select

End Sub
```

However, I failed:-

[image]

Error msg:-

[image]

Debugged:-

[image]

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Which column in Sheet "Data" you want to check the last row? I think that T  but can you confirm it?

Comment: Typo, it shd be D. I hv corrected the macro. The column to check is D.

Comment: Alright! Now another question... Which formulas you want to autofill? Formulas in both B2 and B3 cells?

Comment: Autofill column A & B in Convert sheet.

Comment: Check the answer from CLR. The range you start from (before `.AutoFill`) must be the top of `Destination` range.

Comment: Also, I don't know if you are aware of this, but here `Sheets("Data").Range("D" & Rows.Count)` you actually get rows count from selected sheet, which is `Convert`. It's not a problem in this case, but may be in another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd advise against using `Selection` in this way, but if you've recorded a macro then you're going to get them in your recording.

You could change this part:

```
Range("B3").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:B" & Sheets("Data").Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

To:

```
Range("A2:B2").Select  '<-- only part being changed
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:B" & Sheets("Data").Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

Or, without `Selection` you would just need to replace those two lines with:

```
Range("A2:B2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:B" & Sheets("Data").Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

Comment: don't forget to fully qualify the `Rows.Count` inside `Range("T" & Rows.Count)` with the worksheet

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
Sub Autofill()
'universal autofill 
'suggested shortcut Ctrl+Shift+D

Dim col As Long
Dim row As Long
Dim myrange As Range

col = ActiveCell.Column
If ActiveCell.Column <> 1 Then
    row = Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column - 1).End(xlUp).row
    Else
    row = Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column + 1).End(xlUp).row
End If

If ActiveCell.row >= row Then Exit Sub

Set myrange = Range(Cells(ActiveCell.row, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(row, col))
ActiveCell.Autofill Destination:=myrange

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will be the exact answer you need, but I hope it helps you get the answer! I avoided using "select"s as they are useless. Then I checked which is the last cell with data on column D and autofilled B3 formula until the calculated value.

```
Public Sub Call_Generate_Data()

Sheets("Convert").Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(Data!RC[4],Links!R1C1:R14C2,2,FALSE)"

Sheets("Convert").Range("B3").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(Data!RC[12]="""",""1/1/2014"",Data!RC[12])"

LastRow = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row


Range("A2:B2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:B" & LastRow & "")

END sub
```